CKEditor 5 when pasting an image it's using the URL from metadata instead of the image itself
I'm using CKEditor 5 with the simple upload plugin.
(1) If I find an image via Chrome and click "Copy Image Address" and paste it, it embeds the image using the url i've copy and pasted as the src. This makes sense.
(2) If I find an image via Chrome and click "Copy Image" and paste it, it also embeds the image using the url not the full image that is in the clipboard. This doesn't make sense. Presumably Chrome puts the URL in the metadata of the image or something and then CKEditor is preferring that.
(3) If I find an image on my computer and copy and paste it, it uploads the image using the simple upload plugin and then uses the returned url as the "src" of the image.
How can I prevent (2) from happening and make it so that when I paste an image, the full image not just a url, it always uploads the image in the same way as (3)?
